# Error installing Chocolatey via Ansible on Windows

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, ansible, chocolatey

I have a problem installing Chocolatey and Chocolatey packages using Ansible on Windows Server 2008 R2. Everything worked fine on Windows Server 2012 R2 (it has built-in PowerShell v3.0).

I had a problem running the PowerShell scripts in the [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_windows.html), but I ran `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`, which helped. I installed Windows PowerShell 3.0 so Ansible could run. Now, when I run the playbook, I have this error:

```
failed: [192.168.1.1] => {"failed": true, "parsed": false}

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                              
d----         6/16/2015   6:16 AM            chocInstall                       
Downloading https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/package/chocolatey/ to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip
Download 7Zip commandline tool
Downloading https://chocolatey.org/7za.exe to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\7za.exe
Extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall...
Installing chocolatey on this machine
{
    "changed":  false,
    "msg":  "The term \u0027C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\chocolatey\\chocInstall\\tools\>\chocolateyInstall.ps1\u0027 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.",
    "failed":  true
}

7-Zip (A) 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\chocolatey.zip

Extracting  _rels\.rels
Extracting  chocolatey.nuspec
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateysetup.psm1
Extracting  tools\init.ps1
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\choco.exe
Extracting  tools\chocolateyInstall\choco.exe.ignore
Extracting  package\services\metadata\core-properties\61804721eec44e8592a61904d0a62022.psmdcp
Extracting  [Content_Types].xml

Everything is Ok

Files: 9
Size:       3738621
Compressed: 1259522


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

After second run, I have a different error:

```
failed: [192.168.1.1] => {"changed": false, "failed": true}
msg: The specified module 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I noticed that Ansible has a problem unpacking Chocolatey from `%TEMP%` to `%PROGRAMDATA%`. So, after running `chocolateyInstall.ps1` from `%TEMP%\chocolatey\helpers` (I think it's good path) I have this error:

```
failed: [192.168.1.1] => {"changed": false, "choco_error_cmd": "choco.exe list --local-only chocolatey", "choco_error_log": "",
"failed": true} msg: Error checking installation status for chocolatey

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I need to automate the installation and configuration tools such as: jdk, tomcat, firefox, etc. Here is an example of my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  vars:
    java:
      JAVA_HOME: "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_76"
  tasks:
#   INSTALL FIREFOX
    - name: install_firefox
      win_chocolatey:
        name: firefox -y
        state: present
#   INSTALL AND SET JAVA_HOME
    - name: install_and_set_java_home
      win_chocolatey:
        name: jdk7 -y
        version: 7.0.76
        environment: java
        state: present
```

Comment: This is an outstanding first question! I hope you get some upvotes and find an answer!

Comment: If it is only 2008 you are seeing this, it could be having issues installing .net framework 4.0 (as you mentioned in one of your answers). PowerShell installed is also a requirement, which 2008 I believe doesn't come with by default (which you overcame with WMF 3.0).

Comment: It appears you were running into this: https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org/issues/467, which has been fixed and deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified my playbook, now I run it only once but I have the error (same as earlier) about choco installation. If it helps for someone here is the solution for ignoring failure in playbook:

```
---
- hosts: windows
  tasks:
#   INSTALL CHOCO
    - name: install_chocolatey
      win_chocolatey:
        name: chocolatey -y
        state: present
      ignore_errors: yes
#   INSTALL FIREFOX
    - name: install_firefox
      win_chocolatey:
        name: firefox -y
        state: present
.
.
.
```

I hope it will help ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the solution.. the reported issue is with encoding
Ansible uses by default encoding and language as
ansible.cfg

```
...
module_lang    = C
...
```

but you can override this to host specific variable as

```
ansible_module_lang=cp1252
ansible_ssh_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: PowerShell v3 - Start-Process -Wait doesn't actually wait. https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey.org/issues/467

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the target machine doesn't allow enough memory per PowerShell process.

You can check the current allocation by running:

```
get-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB
```

This is 300MB by default. I generally set it to 2GB for Ansible managed machines, which clears errors around the `System.OutOfMemoryException` right up.

This can be done on the host directly, or with Ansible:

```
- name: set PowerShell memory allowance to 2GB
  win_shell: set-item wsman:localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have some bad encoding in your command.

```
Installing chocolatey on this machine
{
    "changed":  false,
    "msg":  "The term \u0027C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\chocolatey\\chocInstall\\tools\>\chocolateyInstall.ps1\u0027 is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.",
    "failed":  true
}
```

The apostrophes are being printed as [Unicode literals](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)

> "The term \u0027...chocolateyInstall.ps1\u0027 is not recognized..."

Is that just something that Ansible is doing? Can you show us the Chocolatey install playbook section/command?

Like, where do you get this from

```
#   INSTALL FIREFOX
    - name: install_firefox
      win_chocolatey:
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no chocolatey install that I run.

Powershell script win_chocolatey.ps1 should install packages (package manager).

Before the install it should search for chocolatey installation on windows machine. Below the code from win_chocolatey.ps1 script:

```
#!powershell
# This file is part of Ansible
#
# Copyright 2014, Trond Hindenes <trond@hindenes.com>
#
# Ansible is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# Ansible is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with Ansible.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# WANT_JSON
# POWERSHELL_COMMON

$params = Parse-Args $args;
$result = New-Object PSObject;
Set-Attr $result "changed" $false;

If ($params.name)
{
    $package = $params.name
}
Else
{
    Fail-Json $result "missing required argument: name"
}

If ($params.force)
{
    $force = $params.force | ConvertTo-Bool
}
Else
{
    $force = $false
}

If ($params.upgrade)
{
    $upgrade = $params.upgrade | ConvertTo-Bool
}
Else
{
    $upgrade = $false
}

If ($params.version)
{
    $version = $params.version
}
Else
{
    $version = $null
}

If ($params.source)
{
    $source = $params.source.ToString().ToLower()
}
Else
{
    $source = $null
}

If ($params.showlog)
{
    $showlog = $params.showlog | ConvertTo-Bool
}
Else
{
    $showlog = $null
}

If ($params.state)
{
    $state = $params.state.ToString().ToLower()
    If (($state -ne "present") -and ($state -ne "absent"))
    {
        Fail-Json $result "state is $state; must be present or absent"
    }
}
Else
{
    $state = "present"
}

Function Chocolatey-Install-Upgrade
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param()

    $ChocoAlreadyInstalled = get-command choco -ErrorAction 0
    if ($ChocoAlreadyInstalled -eq $null)
    {
        #We need to install chocolatey
        iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"))
        $result.changed = $true
        $script:executable = "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe"
    }
    else
    {
        $script:executable = "choco.exe"

        if ((choco --version) -lt '0.9.9')
        {
            Choco-Upgrade chocolatey 
        }
    }
}


Function Choco-IsInstalled
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$package
    )

    $cmd = "$executable list --local-only $package"
    $results = invoke-expression $cmd

    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_cmd" $cmd
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_log" "$LastExitCode"

        Throw "Error checking installation status for $package" 
    }     

    If ("$results" -match " $package .* (\d+) packages installed.")
    {
        return $matches[1] -gt 0
    }

    $false
}

Function Choco-Upgrade 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$package,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [string]$version,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
        [string]$source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
        [bool]$force
    )

    if (-not (Choco-IsInstalled $package))
    {
        throw "$package is not installed, you cannot upgrade"
    }

    $cmd = "$executable upgrade -dv -y $package"

    if ($version)
    {
        $cmd += " -version $version"
    }

    if ($source)
    {
        $cmd += " -source $source"
    }

    if ($force)
    {
        $cmd += " -force"
    }

    $results = invoke-expression $cmd

    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_cmd" $cmd
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_log" "$results"
        Throw "Error installing $package" 
    }

    if ("$results" -match ' upgraded (\d+)/\d+ package\(s\)\. ')
    {
        if ($matches[1] -gt 0)
        {
            $result.changed = $true
        }
    }
}

Function Choco-Install 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$package,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [string]$version,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
        [string]$source,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
        [bool]$force,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=5)]
        [bool]$upgrade
    )

    if (Choco-IsInstalled $package)
    {
        if ($upgrade)
        {
            Choco-Upgrade -package $package -version $version -source $source -force $force
        }

        return
    }

    $cmd = "$executable install -dv -y $package"

    if ($version)
    {
        $cmd += " -version $version"
    }

    if ($source)
    {
        $cmd += " -source $source"
    }

    if ($force)
    {
        $cmd += " -force"
    }

    $results = invoke-expression $cmd

    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_cmd" $cmd
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_log" "$results"
        Throw "Error installing $package" 
    }

     $result.changed = $true
}

Function Choco-Uninstall 
{
    [CmdletBinding()]

    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
        [string]$package,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
        [string]$version,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)]
        [bool]$force
    )

    if (-not (Choco-IsInstalled $package))
    {
        return
    }

    $cmd = "$executable uninstall -dv -y $package"

    if ($version)
    {
        $cmd += " -version $version"
    }

    if ($force)
    {
        $cmd += " -force"
    }

    $results = invoke-expression $cmd

    if ($LastExitCode -ne 0)
    {
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_cmd" $cmd
        Set-Attr $result "choco_error_log" "$results"
        Throw "Error uninstalling $package" 
    }

     $result.changed = $true
}
Try
{
    Chocolatey-Install-Upgrade

    if ($state -eq "present")
    {
        Choco-Install -package $package -version $version -source $source `
            -force $force -upgrade $upgrade
    }
    else
    {
        Choco-Uninstall -package $package -version $version -force $force
    }

    Exit-Json $result;
}
Catch
{
     Fail-Json $result $_.Exception.Message
}
```

As you see it install chocolatey if it is not found on machine.

Powershell script to install chocolatey is downloaded from https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1

One more thing... in chocolatey install logs there is an exception

> 2015-06-17 01:13:40,156 [ERROR] - Error deserializing response of type
>   chocolatey.infrastructure.app.configuration.ConfigFileSettings:
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>
> 2015-06-17 01:13:40,187 [ERROR] - Exception of type System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I found somewhere that I should use:

> winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="MemoryInMB"}

but it don't help the installation

Answer (score 0):

It's stupid to admit but so simple solution as changing order of instalation helps the second run error.

I think there was a problem with JAVA_HOME system variable (I installed first jdk 7 and setted for it variable), chocolatey installation of tomcat 7 requires installation of java 8 (strange) and sets system variable to jdk8.

My playbook installs now tomcat, jdk7, sets system variable to jdk7 (I'm trying to do this with powershell) and then installs other things. I still have the first error (while installing chocolatey)

```
---
- hosts: windows
  vars:
    java:
      JAVA_HOME: "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_76"
  tasks:
#   INSTALL FIREFOX
    - name: install_firefox
      win_chocolatey:
        name: firefox -y
        state: present
#   TOMCAT INSTALL
    - name: install_tomcat
      win_chocolatey:
        name: tomcat -y
        version: 7.0.59
        state: present
#   INSTALL AND SET JAVA_HOME
    - name: install_and_set_java_home
      win_chocolatey:
        name: jdk7 -y
        version: 7.0.76
        environment: java
        state: present
#   STOP TOMCAT SERVICE
    - name: tomcat_service_auto_stop
      win_service:
        name: Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7
        start_mode: auto
        state: stopped
...
...
...
#   DOWNLOAD SERVER.XML FOR TOMCAT
    - name: download_server_xml
      win_get_url: 
        url: http://192.168.1.107:8000/server.xml
        dest: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\conf\server.xml
#   DOWNLOAD SQL DRIVER
    - name: download_sql_driver
      win_get_url: 
        url: http://192.168.1.107:8000/sqljdbc4.jar
        dest: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\lib\sqljdbc4.jar
#   OPEN PORT 80 FOR TOMCAT
    - name: Open_Port_80_for_Tomcat
      script: ../scripts/portsWin2008.ps1
#   START TOMCAT SERVICE
    - name: tomcat_service_start
      win_service:
        name: Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7
        state: started
```

Comment: As you said its look like "Unicode issue"..   I have same problem i am using ansible-1.9.4 and default chocolatey i.e 0.9.9.8   when ansible use win_choco  module..  i)It talk to winrm where it execute powershell scripts .. then handed controll to chocolatey .. ii)chocolatey execute again some ps scripts to run desire module...   Though i did not get this problem of  "ansible" or  "chocolatey"  or any other place... did anyone resolved this issue???